# Subir imagen con codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Controlador:

```
public function generate($id,$type){
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($method != 'POST'){
            json_output(400,array('status' => 400,'message' => 'Bad request.'));
        } else {
            $config['upload_path'] = './files/';
            $config['allowed_type'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '2024';
            $config['max_height'] = '2008';

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('fileImagen')){
                json_output($response['status'],$this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $file_info = $this->upload->data();
                $descrption = $this->input->post('description');
                $location = $this->input->post('location');
                $date = date("Y-m-d");
                $time = date("H:i:s", strtotime('+12 hours'));
                //$file = $file_info['file_name'];
                $text = $this->input->post('titImagen');

               $data = array(
                  'usuario' => $id,
                  'tipo' => $type,
                  'fecha' => $date,
                  'hora' => $time,
                  'obsUsuario' => $descrption,
                  'localizacion' => $location,
                  'foto' => $text

                );

                $this->load->model('Reportmodel');
                $response = $this->Reportmodel->create($data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Modelo

```
public function create($data){
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->insert('reporte',$data);
        if($this->db->trans_status() == FALSE){
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
            return array('status' => 500,'message' => 'Internal server error.');
        } else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
            return array('status' => 200,'message' => 'Registrado correctamente');
        }  
    }
```

Agrega los datos perfectamente a la base de datos, pero la imagen no la sube, estoy enviando la imagen vía POSTMAN, ya que es API, alguien sabe que esta mal? la carpeta donde se guardan los datos es en una carpeta creada `files` en la raíz de codeigniter.

Estaba viendo que posiblemente sea por mi htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Alguien sabe cual puede ser el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo el codigo de como yo lo hago espero te sirva

Controlador:

```
public function update_user_profile() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $date = $this->utilities->getDateTime();
        $id_user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        if ($this->form_validation->run('update_user') == FALSE) {
            $this->form_user_profile($id_user);
        } else {
            $user = $this->Users_model->get($id_user);
            $user_name = $this->input->post('user_name', TRUE);
            $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email', TRUE);
            $fecha_nac = $this->input->post('user_birthdate', TRUE);
            $user_modified = $date;
            if ($_FILES['userfile']['name'] == NULL) {
                $user_img_profile = $user->user_img_profile;
            } else {

                $ram = $this->utilities->randomString(25);
                $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
                $extension_img = end($tmp);

                $user_img_profile = $ram . '.' . $extension_img;

                $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/users_img/';
//              'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|jpeg|png|iso|dmg|zip|rar|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|csv|ods|odt|odp|pdf|rtf|sxc|sxi|txt|exe|avi|mpeg|mp3|mp4|3gp",
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '5000000';
                $config['quality'] = '90%';
                $config['file_name'] = $user_img_profile;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error', $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->form_user_profile($id_user);
                }
            }

            $user_db = [
                'user_email' => $user_email,
                'user_name' => $user_name,
                'user_modified' => $user_modified,
                'user_img_profile' => $user_img_profile,
                'user_birthdate' => $fecha_nac,
            ];
            $id = $this->Users_model->update($id_user, $user_db);
            if ($id > 0) {
                $_SESSION['user_img'] = $user_img_profile;

                $ls = $this->utilities->add_log("Actualizacion de Perfil ID: " . $id_user, $_SESSION['user_id']);
                $this->utilities->set_message('perfil', 'message_success', $this->lang->line('users_success_update_profile'));
            } else {
                $this->utilities->set_message('perfil', 'message_error', $this->lang->line('users_error_update_profile'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Modelo:

```
class Users_model extends CI_Model {

    //put your code here
    private $table = "users";
    private $id = "id";

public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function update($id, $data) {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
}
```

Comment: me funciona perfecto, pero tuve que quitar el _ $ram = $this->utilities->randomString(25);_ me marca error, sabes porque?

Comment: Lo que pasa que es una función mía para generarle un nombre a la imagen.

Comment: marcala com que te soluciono el problema